# Plotly hover_data does not work with dict?

Tags: python, plotly

As stated from [plotly docs](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.express.scatter_mapbox.html) it is possible to pass dict with key set to columns and values set to booleans in order to manage what is shown and what's not or formatting:

```py
hover_data = {"killed":True,"group":True,"lat":False,"long":False,"year":False}

fig = px.scatter_mapbox(df_clean, lat="lat", lon="long", hover_name="hover_title",
                        animation_frame="year",
                        color_discrete_sequence=["red"],
                        opacity = 1,
                        zoom=1, size="killed",
                        hover_data=hover_data)
```

This produces

```
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

What do I miss here? 
I saw someone used dict({...}) in plotly context but i does not see how it works neither it does not help.

```
Traceback: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-75-881c99be1dc5> in <module>
      7                         opacity = 1,
      8                         zoom=1, size="killed",
----> 9                         hover_data=hover_data)
     10 # fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="open-street-map")
     11 

/opt/anaconda/envs/Python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/express/_chart_types.py in scatter_mapbox(data_frame, lat, lon, color, text, hover_name, hover_data, custom_data, size, animation_frame, animation_group, category_orders, labels, color_discrete_sequence, color_discrete_map, color_continuous_scale, range_color, color_continuous_midpoint, opacity, size_max, zoom, center, mapbox_style, title, template, width, height)
   1008     symbol mark on a Mapbox map.
   1009     """
-> 1010     return make_figure(args=locals(), constructor=go.Scattermapbox)
   1011 
   1012 

/opt/anaconda/envs/Python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/express/_core.py in make_figure(args, constructor, trace_patch, layout_patch)
   1366 
   1367     args, trace_specs, grouped_mappings, sizeref, show_colorbar = infer_config(
-> 1368         args, constructor, trace_patch
   1369     )
   1370     grouper = [x.grouper or one_group for x in grouped_mappings] or [one_group]

/opt/anaconda/envs/Python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/express/_core.py in infer_config(args, constructor, trace_patch)
   1209             all_attrables += [group_attr]
   1210 
-> 1211     args = build_dataframe(args, all_attrables, array_attrables)
   1212     if constructor in [go.Treemap, go.Sunburst] and args["path"] is not None:
   1213         args = process_dataframe_hierarchy(args)

/opt/anaconda/envs/Python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/express/_core.py in build_dataframe(args, attrables, array_attrables)
    940         # argument_list and field_list ready, iterate over them
    941         # Core of the loop starts here
--> 942         for i, (argument, field) in enumerate(zip(argument_list, field_list)):
    943             length = len(df_output)
    944             if argument is None:

RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Comment: can you put the full error traceback?

Comment: @HoxhaAlban added. Would appreciate help, however, I cannot find proper use of dicts in express library. There is implementation but with the full library

Comment: i am not able to reproduce the error, can you share your dataframe and your plotly version?

Comment: it would help to have some data to work with, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I had the same problem and it worked after I updated Plotly version. Now I'm using 4.8.2